# AngularJs get template name from dynamic templateurl

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following route definition:

```
.......... 
when('/:templateFile', 
{
  templateUrl: function (param) { return 'views/' + param.templateFile + '.html' }
})
..........
```

The next piece of code listens to the route is changing. If the user is not authenticated and the next page/template to which he wants to navigate is not the login page, then the user is redirected to login page.

Everything works fine except that the `next.templateUrl` value is actually `function (param) { return 'views/' + param.templateFile + '.html'` instead of `views/login.html`, for example.

alert(next.templateUrl) will display `function (param) { return 'views/' + param.templateFile + '.html'`.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {            
        if (!$rootScope.IsAuth) {

            alert(next.templateUrl);  // problem

            if (next.templateUrl === "views/login.html") {
            } else {
                $location.path("/login");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas how I can get the next templateurl when using dynamic templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since `templateUrl` is indeed a function you can try to use it as function. If you invoke it with route parameters it should return a template URL:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {            
        if (!$rootScope.IsAuth) {

            var templateUrl = next.templateUrl(next.params);

            if (templateUrl === "views/login.html") {
                // ...
            } 
            else {
                    $location.path("/login");
            }
        }
    });
});
```